# How to apply distinct() to array of objects RxJS?

Tags: rxjs6, redux-observable

I am fetching a pets list from the swagger pets API. I want to remove pets with duplicate ids and then send it to React to avoid the duplicate key problem. I tried the code below but does not work for me. Can anyone help me out with this?

I am new to RxJS so want to remove the commented code which filters distinct objects based on pet id.

```
export function fetchPetEpic(action$) {
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType('GET_PETS'),
        switchMap(action => 
            ajax.getJSON(`https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=${action.payload}`).pipe(
                map( response => response.map( (pet) => ({
                    id: pet.id,
                    pet: pet.pet
                }))),
                distinct( petList => petList.id),
                // map( petList => petList.filter((pet, index, list) => {
                //                     return list.map(petObj =>
                //                         petObj.id).indexOf(pet.id) === index;
                //                     })),
                map(response => petActions.setPets(response))
        )),
        catchError( error => ({ type: 'ERROR_PETS_FETCH', payload: error})),
    )
}
```

Suppose the pets array is something like [
{ id: 1, pet: dog}, { id: 2, pet: cat }, { id: 3, pet: fish}, { id: 2, pet: rat }, { id: 4, pet: parrot}, { id: 1, pet: owl }
]

Expected output:[{ id: 1, pet: dog}, { id: 2, pet: cat }, { id: 3, pet: fish}, { id: 4, pet: parrot}]

The output I am getting is the same array as input.

Comment: The docs for `distidnct` say, "Returns an Observable that emits all items emitted by the source Observable that are distinct by comparison from previous items." Unless you get a duplicate one right after the other, `distinct` won't cut it. In fact-- I think you're better off without. You want to operate on the set as an event, not individual items within the set as events.

Comment: But if you check the link in official docs it has the same problem solved - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinct. Cannot figure out why it's not working for me !

Comment: @seniorquico could you please look at the above link which I mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getJSON` function will return an observable that emits one item (the response) and completes. (Or, it can emit one error.) Given your happy path example of returning an array...

The following `map` operator will receive the deserialized JSON array and map it to a new array. That is, the `map` operator will have exactly one input event and result in exactly one output event.

```js
map(response => response.map(pet => ({
  id: pet.id,
  name: pet.name,
  status: pet.status,
}))),
```

The `distinct` operator works across multiple *events*. For each event, it filters out any duplicates (with the definition of duplicate customizable as you've noted). The following `distinct` operator will always pass through your *single* event. Also, take note that `petList` is an *array*. Arrays don't have an `id` property, so the lambda will return `undefined`. It doesn't really matter what the lambda returns, though. Because there's only a single event, it's not using the return value in any comparisons.

```js
distinct(petList => petList.id),
```

It appears you're expecting `distinct` to process each element of the array. To accomplish this, you can use `from` to convert the array to an observable and `concatMap` to emit each element in order. With multiple events flowing through the pipe, `distinct` can do its magic:

```js
...
concatMap(from), // shorthand for: `concatMap(response => from(response)),`
map(pet => ({
  id: pet.id,
  name: pet.name,
  status: pet.status,
})),
distinct(pet => pet.id),
...
```

However, this change would result in emitting multiple Redux actions (one for each distinct pet). We can use the `reduce` operator to accumulate each of the distinct pets back into a single array before emitting the Redux action.

```js
...
reduce((pets, pet) => [...pets, pet], []),
map(pets => petActions.setPets(pets)),
...
```

Let's put it all together:

```js
export function fetchPetEpic(action$) {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType('GET_PETS'),
    switchMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=${action.payload}`).pipe(
        concatMap(from), // shorthand for: `concatMap(response => from(response)),`
        map(pet => ({
          id: pet.id,
          name: pet.name,
          status: pet.status,
        })),
        distinct(pet => pet.id),
        reduce((pets, pet) => [...pets, pet], []),
        map(pets => petActions.setPets(pets)),
        catchError(error => ({ type: 'ERROR_PETS_FETCH', payload: error })),
      )
    ),
  )
}
```

One final note: Something looks off between the example data you provided and the `map` you're applying. If the array looks like the following:

> [ { id: 1, pet: dog }, ...

Then each element doesn't have `name` or `status` properties, just `id` and `pet` properties. Maybe the following is intended?

```js
map(item => ({
  id: item.id,
  name: item.pet.name,
  status: item.pet.status,
})),
```

Or maybe it's just a problem with the example data you provided. Either way, I'd recommend double checking the map to ensure it projects your values as expected.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Worked for me and now I know where it went wrong !

Comment: This is misusing the `distinct` and `reduce`operators in my opinion. they are built for diferent purposes rather than manipulating arrays.